# Joining string, variable, and array index all together to a variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to do something out of my league, but I don't see how else I can achieve it.

I have two array variables.

```
<?php
$mobile_eu = array("alb", "bul");
$m_alb = array(array("Albanian"), array("test@test.com"),
    array("test2@test.com", "test3@test.com");
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is, get `alb` from `$mobile_eu`, prepend a string to the value, and then access `$m_alb` from it with `[0][0]` index. Something like...

```
function createLink($category) {
  foreach ($category as $short) {
  $langcode = "\$m_" . $short . [0][0];
  }
}
```

and yes, it doesn't work. When I dumped it, all it shows is

```
string 'alb0' (length=4)
```

What I hope to achieve here is to get

```
string 'Albanian' (length=8)
```

Is there any way to get this?

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Use `arrays` and keys. `$arr['alb'][0][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$mobile_eu = array("alb", "bul");
$m_alb = array(array("Albanian"), array("test@test.com"),
    array("test2@test.com", "test3@test.com"));


echo ${'m_'.$mobile_eu[0]}[0][0];
```

[prints](https://3v4l.org/hP10o) `Albania`.

see also: http://docs.php.net/language.variables.variable

---

But I think you should structure your data in another way, so you don't need something like this. E.g. instead of having a variable $m_alb and another $m_bul you could have an array where 'alb' and 'bul' are keys/elements:

```
<?php
createLinks( array('alb','bul') );

function createLinks($regions) {
    static $data = array ( /* using static only as an example for "some data source" */
        'alb' => array(
            array("Albanian"), /* it would certainly be nice if you could give */
            array("test@test.com"), /* those elements key-names with some meaning */
            array("test2@test.com", "test3@test.com")
        ),
        'bul' => array(
            array("Bulgaria"),
            array("test5@test.com"),
            array("test6@test.com", "test7@test.com")
        ),
    );

    foreach( $regions as $r ) {
        echo $data[$r][0][0], "<br />\r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed!

Comment: But please, consider seriously what u_mulder and I are trying to tell you: structure your data differentely. Just a second, I'll add an example.

Comment: Wow. I never thought about structuring data like this. I'll follow your advice. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

Might be this will helps you.

**Solution :** I have made some modifications in your createlink function Kindly check those as below:

```
function createLink($category) {
  foreach ($category as $short) {
    global $m_alb;
    $arrayName = "m_" . $short;
    $newArray = $$arrayName;
    var_dump($newArray[0][0]);
  }
}
```

I have made $m_alb array as the global because the with out this we will get an `Notice: Undefined variable: m_alb.` As the $m_alb array is not in the scope of createlink function. Now you can call your createlink function and check the result.

Hope this will works for you.

Comment: This method would require me to declare all `$_XXX` variables as global, does it not? Anyway, thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Yes that's the limitation of code that I had posted.